# Microsoft Visual C++2010を参照しているプロジェクトからそれを取り除きたい

Tags: visual-studio

古くから使っているC++の実行ファイルを再利用したいのですが、Microsoft Visual C++2010がない旨のエラーが出てしまいます。
Microsoft Visual C++2017を入れた環境で動かしたいのですが、その場合どのように対処したらいいでしょうか。
Visual Studioのプロジェクトはあり、C++のソースで構成されています。

Comment: 「Microsoft Visual C++2010がない旨のエラー」という抽象的な表現では他人には伝わりません。具体的にどのような操作をしたのか、またメッセージは一字一句違わず記述してください。

Comment: 対象のソリューション/プロジェクトをVisualStudio2017で開こうとすれば、それをVisualStudio2017で使えるようにアップグレードしますか？と聞いてくるダイアログが表示されると思うのですが、どうでしょうか？ [以前のバージョンの Visual Studio からの C++ プロジェクトのアップグレード](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/porting/upgrading-projects-from-earlier-versions-of-visual-cpp?view=msvc-170) 単に実行ファイルを動かそうとしているだけならこちらのページが参考になるでしょう。[サポートされている最新の Visual C++ 再頒布可能パッケージのダウンロード](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170#visual-studio-2010-vc-100-sp1-no-longer-supported)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

話が、あなたの作ったプログラム (EXE/DLL) を別マシンにコピーして動かそうとすると動かない、であるとして

たぶん正確なエラーメッセージは Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Runtime Redistributables 日本語訳すると再配布可能パッケージがインストールされていない、なのでしょう。既にコメントがついている通り、あなたの作ったプログラムを実行したいマシン上で [Visual C++ 再配布可能パッケージのダウンロード](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170#visual-studio-2010-vc-100-sp1-no-longer-supported) ページより VC2010 用 `vcredist_x86.exe` または `vcredist_x64.exe` をダウンロードしてインストールしてください。あなたのそのプログラムが 32bit 構成なら windows 自体の x86/x64 に関係なく `vcredist_x86.exe` が必要です。同様、あなたのプログラムが 64bit 構成なら windows も 64bit 版、なおかつ `vcredist_x64.exe` が必要ということになります。大した分量ではないし後々の手間を考えると両方をインストールすることをお勧めします。

んで、上記の話をわざわざ人の手でやる必要は本来なくて、そのためにインストーラーなるものが作れるようになっています。あなたのプログラム用のインストーラーを正しく作れば、上記を手続きを自動でやってくれるように構成することができます。普通は実行形式ファイルを単にコピーして別マシン上で動かそうとはしないものです。

話が、実行環境に VS2010 用 `vcredist` を入れずにあなたの作ったプログラムを動かしたい、であるなら：
vs2010 で作ったソースコードプロジェクトを vs2017 に移行させることができます（この組み合わせは手元にないのので当方では未確認）。移行してビルドしてデバッグしてください。 Windows 10 以後なら VC2015-2019 用 `vcredist` がまとまったものが入っているので、特に何か追加インストールしなくても動くと思われます。
# 潜在していたバグが顕在化する可能性があるし、ソースコードレベルでの修正が必要となるかもしれません。なので要デバッグ。

visual studio は既に 2022 が出ていますので、わざわざ古い vs2017 に移行するくらいなら vs2022 のほうがおすすめかも。まあ 2022 用 `vcredist` が必要になるのは同じことですが。

Comment: こちらの方法で解決しました。ありがとうございました。→vs2010 で作ったソースコードプロジェクトを vs2017 に移行させることができます